# CakePHP: different routing based on extensions

Tags: cakephp, routes, cakephp-2.0

I am trying to route to a different action based on the url-extension in Cake2. I have this working route:

```
Router::connect(
    '/:lang/:product/:version/:filename', 
    array(
        'controller'    => 'pages', 
        'action'        => 'run', 
        'lang'          => ':lang', 
        'product'       => ':product', 
        'version'       => ':version',
        'filename'      => ':filename'
    ),
    array(
        'pass'          => array('filename'),
        'lang'          => '[a-zA-Z]{2}',
        'product'       => '[a-zA-Z0-9_!\-]+',
        'version'       => '[0-9]{3}',
        'filename'      => '[a-zA-Z0-9_!\-\.]+'
    )
);
```

For the new route I simply added the extension and changed the action.

```
Router::connect(
    '/:lang/:product/:version/:filename.json', 
    array(
        'controller'    => 'pages', 
        'action'        => 'get', 
        'lang'          => ':lang', 
        'product'       => ':product', 
        'version'       => ':version',
        'filename'      => ':filename'
    ),
    array(
        'pass'          => array('filename'),
        'lang'          => '[a-zA-Z]{2}',
        'product'       => '[a-zA-Z0-9_!\-]+',
        'version'       => '[0-9]{3}',
        'filename'      => '[a-zA-Z0-9_!\-\.]+'
    )
);
```

For some reason though the `run` action is still called (including the ext, so /../pages/json/run.ctp).

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hmm its probably because of the regexp on the first route

on the first rule you're telling cake that `:filename` can contain a point `[a-zA-Z0-9_!\-\.]+` So the router will always match the first rule..

try changing the order of the routes, from specific to general

also check how cake manages the [file extensions on routes](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#index-4)

Hope this helps

Comment: thanks for your reply. Unfortunately that didn't help. I changed the order of the routes and took out the dot .. still Cake dispatches to the `run` action